# regular expression matching a number of 7 digits where the 4th is successor or predecessor

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that checks the following :

a number with 7 digits having the following format : xxxyxxx
where y is different than 0 and is successor or predecessor (x+1 or x-1)

example:

```
4443444 --> match
4445444 --> match
4442444 --> doesn't match
```

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: I tried this regex : ^(\d){3}(?\1)\d\1{3}$ , but I'm not getting how to check if a number is successor or predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a smart way of doing this with a RegExp.

You could simply force your way through, though :

`1{3}21{3}|2{3}[13]2{3}|3{3}[24]3{3}|4{3}[35]4{3}|5{3}[46]5{3}|6{3}[57]6{3}|7{3}[68]7{3}|8{3}[79]8{3}|9{3}89{3}`

See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/dn0US3/1).

```
1{3}21{3}       `1` 3 times + `2` + `1` 3 times
|               OR
2{3}[13]2{3}    `2` 3 times + (`1` OR `3`) + `2` 3 times
|               ...
3{3}[24]3{3}
|
4{3}[35]4{3}
|
5{3}[46]5{3}
|
6{3}[57]6{3}
|
7{3}[68]7{3}
|
8{3}[79]8{3}
|
9{3}89{3}
```